# How do I authenticate a Vue.js progressive web app with the Microsoft Graph

Tags: javascript, vue.js, oauth-2.0

I have a Vue.js app. This app is a progressive web app, so it's intended to primarily run on the client-side. However, during the initial start-up, I need to authenticate the user in my Azure Active Directory, get data associated with their account, and store it for offline use.

I have a server-side API in place already for retrieving the data associated with a user account. I also know how to store it for offline use. However, my question is: how do I authenticate with the Microsoft Graph from my Vue.js app? Everything I see relies on using Node.js middleware, but unless I'm misunderstanding something, my progressive web app isn't a Node.js app. It's just straight up JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.

If the user closes the app, then revisits it in a couple of days, I believe I would need to use the refresh token to get a new access token. Still, once again, everything I see relies on Node.js middleware. I believe I need a solution that works purely in Vue.js / JavaScript. Am I mistaken?

**Updates**

1) Installed the Microsoft Graph Client via NPM (`npm install @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client --save`). This installed v1.7.0.

2) In my Vue.js app, I have:

```
import * as MicrosoftGraph from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client';
import * as Msal from 'msal';

let clientId = '<some guid>';
let scopes = ['user.read'];
let redirectUrl = 'http://localhost:1234/';  // This is registered in Azure AD.

let cb = (message, token, error, tokenType) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.log(token);
    console.log(tokenType);
  }
}

let reg = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(clientId, undefined, cb, { redirectUrl });
let authProvider = new MicrosoftGraph.MSALAuthenticationProvider(reg, scopes);
```

The last line generates an error that says: `export 'MSALAuthenticationProvider' (imported as 'MicrosoftGraph') was not found in '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client'`

Comment: Hey, I checked quickly on the documentation, support for client-side javascript seems to be up (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript). 
You should be able to authenticate users directly on your webapp, without using Node.js.

Comment: @LoïcMonard Thank you for pointing this out. Is there an example anywhere of this working? Everything seems pieced together and in a great deal of flux. At the moment, I'm working to import the MSALAuthentiationProvider without any luck.

Comment: @user687554 could you provide code how are you importing that provider? I've just set up project and example from github is working for me.

Comment: @MaxSinev - I just added the code showing how i'm importing the provider

Comment: @user687554 I guess your import might be wrong, you try to import everything from the lib, while in the sample they're just importing { Client }, as is "import { Client } from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client";"

Answer (score 4):

> The last line generates an error that says: `export 'MSALAuthenticationProvider' (imported as 'MicrosoftGraph') was not found in '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client'`

This error occurs because the main script ([`lib/src/index.js`](https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client@1.7.0/lib/src/index.js)) of `@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client` does not export that symbol. You'll notice that logging `MicrosoftGraph.MSALAuthenticationProvider` yields `undefined`. Actually, the main script is intended to be run in Node middleware.

However, `@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client` provides browser scripts that *do* make `MSALAuthenticationProvider` available:

#### **[`lib/graph-js-sdk-web.js`](https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client@1.7.0/lib/graph-js-sdk-web.js)**

- [*browserified* bundle](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/143a5e0/package.json#L35) (not tree-shakable)
- [sets `window.MicrosoftGraph`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/143a5e0/browser-wrapper.js#L11), which contains `MSALAuthenticationProvider`
- does *not* export any symbols itself

```js
import '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/graph-js-sdk-web'

let authProvider = new window.MicrosoftGraph.MSALAuthenticationProvider(/* ... */)
```

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-yxw0b?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fms-graph-init.js)

#### **[`lib/es/browser/index.js`](https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client@1.7.0/lib/es/browser/index.js)**

- ES Modules (tree-shakable)
- exports `MSALAuthenticationProvider`

```js
import { MSALAuthenticationProvider } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/es/browser'

let authProvider = new MSALAuthenticationProvider(/* ... */)
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-microsoft-graph-authentication-provider-in-browser-ki9t9?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fms-graph-init.js)

#### **[`lib/src/browser/index.js`](https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client@1.7.0/lib/src/browser/index.js)**

- CommonJS module (not tree-shakable)
- exports `MSALAuthenticationProvider`

```js
import { MSALAuthenticationProvider } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/browser'

let authProvider = new MSALAuthenticationProvider(/* ... */)
```

[demo 3](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-microsoft-graph-authentication-provider-in-browser-sns9f?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fms-graph-init.js)